# How to refactor a prop in React with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to refactor a component in my App.tsx file to it's own file (InvoiceList.ts).

I have moved the component to another file and imported it within App.tsx, but I am getting an error of `Cannot find name 'InvoiceDataType'`

When I bring the component back into the App.tsx, file, I get no errors. Why am I getting that error and how can I fix it.

**Note**: This is my first time using Typescript with React and so I am still learning how to fuse the two together.

```js
// App.tsx
import { InvoiceList } from "./components/InvoiceList";

const App = () => {
  const data: InvoiceDataType = {
    customerName: "Google",
    invoices: [
      { id: 123, name: "Dev work", total: "20.00", paymentStatus: "paid" },
      {
        id: 456,
        name: "More Dev work",
        total: "50.00",
        paymentStatus: "pending",
      },
      {
        id: 789,
        name: "Something different",
        total: "100.00",
        paymentStatus: "paid",
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <InvoiceList invoiceData={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```js
// InvoiceList.tsx
interface IInvoiceListProps {
  invoiceData: InvoiceDataType;
  logo?: string;
}

type InvoiceDataType = {
  customerName: string;
  invoices: InvoiceType[];
};

type PaymentStatusType = "paid" | "pending" | "late";

type InvoiceType = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  total: string;
  paymentStatus: PaymentStatusType;
};

export const InvoiceList = (props: IInvoiceListProps) => {
  const { customerName, invoices } = props.invoiceData;

  const itemStyleContainer = {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{customerName}</h1>
      <hr />

      <div>
        {invoices.map((invoice) => (
          <div key={invoice.id} style={itemStyleContainer}>
            <div>{invoice.name}</div>

            <div>
              {invoice.total} - {invoice.paymentStatus}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the problem is occuring because `InvoiceDataType` is no longer defined inside of `App.tsx` after your refactoring.

To make it available for use inside of `App.tsx`, you should export it from `InvoiceList.ts` and then import it inside of `App.tsx` for use.

For example:

```
// App.tsx
import { InvoiceList, InvoiceDataType } from "./components/InvoiceList";
...
```

```
// InvoicList.tsx
...
export type InvoiceDataType = {
  customerName: string;
  invoices: InvoiceType[];
};
...
```

Comment: Thanks, @rexessilfie! Is this a common thing to do with React and Typescript?

Comment: No problem! And yes, in my use so far I have adopted the pattern of export and then importing types as needed inside of a project. Sometimes I keep all types defined elsewhere in a separate `types.ts` file. Here is a quick medium article explaining some approaches for dealing with types in typescript! https://medium.com/mintbean-io/how-i-organize-my-typescript-types-d9ae7f3ac30f